# AngularJS 1.0.7 locationProvider undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 web application.

I´m trying to use $locationProvider in my app.js (in order to run htm5Mode), but when I run it, I get $locationProvider is undefined.

Do I need to load any extra js library? I don´t find any docs.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $routeParams, $locationProvider) {

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `$routeParams` in your dependency injection

```
['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$routeParams', '$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $routeParams, $locationProvider)
```

Comment: I´m not using it and I forgot it :).